# How to use where clause within my big join Mysql query to restrict results?

Tags: mysql

I have successfully written this join query below to get all the data I need from each individual table in the database within one query.  Unfortunately, it gives me ALL the data from these individual tables.  I only need data that corresponds to e.Design_ID, if e.Design_ID = 1  I have tried a few "where e.Design_ID = 1" within this code block, but have not been successful in restricting the query.   I'm stuck.  I'm thinking I may need to restructure my entire query.  My logic may be off...

Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT 
a.SKU,
a.Apparel_ID,
a.Apparel_Color_Abbr,
a.Design_ID,
a.City_ID,
a.Category_ID,
a.SEO_Keyword,
a.OC_Product_ID,
b.Apparel_Color_Palette,
b.Apparel_Name,
b.Apparel_Name_Abbr,
b.Apparel_Type,
b.Google_Feed_Cat,
b.Gender,
b.Age_Group,
b.Retail_Price,
b.Apparel_Description,
c.Apparel_Color,
d.OC_Cat_City_ID,
d.OC_Cat_State_ID,
d.City,
d.State,
e.Design_Name,
e.Design_Description
FROM Complete_City_Products AS a
INNER JOIN Apparel AS b ON a.Apparel_ID = b.Apparel_ID
INNER JOIN Apparel_Colors AS c ON b.Apparel_Color_Palette = c.Apparel_Color_Palette AND a.Apparel_Color_Abbr = c.Apparel_Color_Abbr
INNER JOIN Cities AS d ON a.City_ID = d.City_ID
INNER JOIN Designs AS e ON a.Design_ID = e.Design_ID
";
```

Comment: What about the query do you wish to restrict? Your joins look fine but since you are not limiting the data with a where clause, you will get all the data

Comment: I only want to get data that corresponds to e.Design_ID if e.Design_ID=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
a.SKU,
a.Apparel_ID,
a.Apparel_Color_Abbr,
a.Design_ID,
a.City_ID,
a.Category_ID,
a.SEO_Keyword,
a.OC_Product_ID,
b.Apparel_Color_Palette,
b.Apparel_Name,
b.Apparel_Name_Abbr,
b.Apparel_Type,
b.Google_Feed_Cat,
b.Gender,
b.Age_Group,
b.Retail_Price,
b.Apparel_Description,
c.Apparel_Color,
d.OC_Cat_City_ID,
d.OC_Cat_State_ID,
d.City,
d.State,
e.Design_Name,
e.Design_Description
FROM Complete_City_Products AS a
INNER JOIN Apparel AS b ON a.Apparel_ID = b.Apparel_ID
INNER JOIN Apparel_Colors AS c ON b.Apparel_Color_Palette = c.Apparel_Color_Palette AND a.Apparel_Color_Abbr = c.Apparel_Color_Abbr
INNER JOIN Cities AS d ON a.City_ID = d.City_ID
INNER JOIN Designs AS e ON a.Design_ID = e.Design_ID

WHERE e.Design_ID = 1
";
```

It should work if you put it at the end. Also check correct spelling.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help.   Unfortunately, it does not.  I still get all the other data corresponding to all of the rows of data within "Designs".  The query is not restricted to just the 1 row with e.Design_ID = 1.

Comment: Try to put e.Design_ID = 1 into ()

-> where (e.Design_ID = 1)

Comment: Did you write it in CAPS?

Comment: I'm sorry.  Same result.

Comment: Ok.  This is the correct answer.  I had a completely unrelated bug outside of this code that was causing me to see incorrect results.  Thank you for your help.  This bug was driving me wonky.